# Real world solutions using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, java, spring, dependency-injection

I was reading about DI thoroughly, and it seems interesting. So far, I'm totally living without it.

All the examples i saw are related to JNDI and how DI helps you being more flexible.

What is real life applications/problems that you solved with DI that will be hard to solve in other ways?

**UPDATE**
All the answers till now are educating, but to rephrase the question, I'm looking for examples in your programming life, that made you say "this problem will be best solved with a DI framework".

Comment: This is a discussion not a question. Voting to close.

Comment: you better vote for it being a wiki not close! but I still think its a question, and i intend to choose the programming problem that explains DI the best as my best answer

Comment: @cletus - it's a very valid question. Through seeing what problems other people have used DI to solve, the OP will better understand when and where to use it in his own work.

Comment: @Winston: There is no "answer" to this question however. It's just a bunch of anecdotes that don't really relate to each other. Hence "discussion".

Comment: I agree w/ cletus - this is a discussion, but let's move to CW

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just the other day, I decided to read up on dependency injection. Until then, I only knew the word. Honestly, my reaction to Martin Fowler's [article](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html) was, "That's it?"

I have to agree with [James Shore](http://jamesshore.com/Blog/Dependency-Injection-Demystified.html):

> "Dependency Injection" is a 25-dollar term for a 5-cent concept.

That doesn't mean at all that it's a *bad* concept. But seriously, when an instance `A` needs to work with another instance `B`, it comes down to these choices:

1. let `A` **find** `B`:

   That means `B` must be global. Evil.
2. let `A` **create** `B`:

   Fine, if only `A` needs `B`. As soon as `C` also needs `B`, replace `A` by `C` in this list. Note that a test case would be a `C`, so if you do want to test, this choice is gone as well.
3. **give** `B` to `A`:

   That's dependency injection.

Am I missing something? (Note that I'm from the Python world, so maybe there are language specific points I'm not seeing.)

Comment: It's quite a creative idea.  It may seem like a 5-cent concept now, but did you think of it yourself?  IOC is a very handy pattern.

Comment: @Travis: I totally agree, it's handy and good. But as a global concept (I'm not talking about implementation details and differences between using setters or the constructor, and between using a service locator or the instance directly), it seems very natural. An yes, I have been (kind of -- I'm not saying I'm doing everything right or that I invented the wheel, fire, and electricity) using the pattern before I knew it was called DI.

Comment: The crucial problem with "2. let A create B" is not that C needs B as well. THe problem is that the appropriate kind of B depends on the context that the application is being run under, and we don't want A to know about the context. 
It's like any design pattern - people often come to use them naturally, not knowing or even caring there's a name for what they're doing. The name's useful just so that developers can communicate to one another what they're doing.

Comment: @Andrew Sheperd: Well said, I agree 100%.

Comment: @Andrew Sheperd: Is that different from "programming to an interface"? The name doesn't really matter, but an intuitive name is better than an obscure one

Comment: "Dependency Injection is a 25-dollar term for a 5-cent concept" - indeed - it gives quite a return on investment.

Comment: So wait, when I pass an IComparer to a Dictionary, I'm doing DI? Why does that need a fancy name? :) It's an idea that's been around forever, surely.

Comment: The OP mentioned real life problme, and yet again here is more talk of A, B and C.

Answer (score 7):

Yesterday I found a mobile on the bus. The person who lost it had no clue about the person possessing her mobile. I called her dad and told him I have the mobile of his daughter. So I injected the dependency from me into him. Typically a case of the hollywood principle "Don't call us (because you can't!), we call you". Later he came and picked up his daughters phone.

I'd call that a real world problem which I solved by dependency injection, isn't it?

In my opinion, DI is not THE way to solve problems, for which we would not have another solution. Factories can be another way to solve such problems.
So there is no real answer for your question, because DI is just one way besides others. It is just a pretty hip, although very elegant way.

I really enjoyed DI when I had this DAOs, which needed an SQLMapper. I just had to inject the different mappers into the fatherclass once and the rest was done by configuration. Saved me a lot of time and LOCs, but I still can't name this a problem for which there is no other solution.

Comment: so far this is the most interesting answer, i liked the line (So I injected the dependency from me into him), and the SQLMapper is an example of real-life problem im looking for

Comment: I found the line “So I injected the dependency from me into him” confusing. Which dependency? Dependency on knowing where the phone is or knowing where the owner is? You know where the phone is; the father knows where the owner is. There are now two ways to proceed: either he tells you where the owner is and you get on with the job, or you give the phone to him and let him get on with the job. Which one is called “dependency injection”, and what is the important difference between them that makes one of them called DI and the other not?

Comment: We were both dependent on each other. My method "returnMobile" needs a parameter "owner", the fathers method "getMobile" needs a parameter "posessor".
Which is dependent from whom in what case depends of who has control of the running process. Since this is a real world problem, you would minimize the effort in solving it, if you would program it.
You would design it in a way, that there is a precondition, who has to act. Either the father or me and since I am the object with more information (the number of the father), I would omit the function "getMobile" from the father.

Answer (score 4):

I use dependency injection for testing all the time.  It's also extremely helpful when you have a bunch of large systems that you do not want to directly tie together (extremely loose coupling).

If you're using Java, I would recommend [Google Guice](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/), since it rocks so much.  For C++, I recommend [Qt IOC](http://qtioccontainer.sourceforge.net/).  For .NET, the [Castle Project](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) provides a nice IOC system.  There is also a Spring implementation basically everywhere, but that's boring.

Comment: +1 for the links to other implementations. I didn't know about them.

Answer (score 3):

DI allows you to create applications that can be configured and reconfigured without touching the codebase itself.  Not just urls or settings though; generic objects can be written in code, and then "customized" or configured via XML files to achieve the specific result desired for the given case.

For example, I can create a RegexDetective class where the actual regex it looks for is provided in a setter, and then in my Spring DI XML file, define one actual regex expression for RegexDetective.setRegex() for a deployment of SleuthApp going to London.  Then a few days later I can go back and update the regex in the XML file for another deployment of SleuthApp shipping out to Siberia.

DI also allows one to define specific implementations of interfaces in a similar fashion, outside of the codebase in XML, to modify behavior of an application without actually touching the code, such as setting the AngryDetective or ArcticDetective implementation of the Detective interface, in the DI XML file.

Comment: Isn't your first example just what the Unix people call "data-driven programming"? A much better name IMHO, and a very old idea. http://catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/ch09s01.html

Comment: What? A regex setting requires some mysterious new technology? `var myRegex = new Regex(SleuthAppSettings.Regex);` — done...

Comment: Similarly for the last paragraph: `var detective = SleuthAppSettings.UseAngryDetective ? (IDetective) new AngryDetective() : new ArcticDective();` — this has been done for over 50 years in computer programming...

Comment: @Timwi - the latter is not scalable to any sort of detective if there are more than two or three otherwise you get some horrible mass of potentially unmaintainable code (imagine a detective needs 20 constructor parameters for example...) everywhere you need to create a new Detective.

Answer (score 2):

We run a multimedia service for different countries. We run the same code for everyone but sometimes, business rules are different from one country to another. In this case, we inject different Spring MVC Interceptor for one client or for another.

Then, in the deploy phase, a script "chooses" which DI file is needed, based on the last letters of the files (*fr* for France, *ch* for Switzerland etc...)

- application-context.xml-fr
- application-context.xml-ch
- etc...

That's the only good use I see in DI. I'm not a fan of DI though.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Spring's IoC (DI) container for the last three web apps I've developed.  I don't think its suited to one particular type of problem, rather it's a different way of solving a problem.  It's as you've said, a more flexible approach to large systems.  My personal favourite features of DI are that you can prepare better unit tests because your classes are highly decoupled.  Also important for me is code reuse.  Since I use the container in many apps, I can use the same components and know that their dependencies will be fed in externally.

Answer (score 0):

In large multi-module applications using DI, a module only depends on the interfaces on the collaborator of its classes, which **cuts compile-time dependency graphs**.

In the context of **frameworks** (calling "your" functional code, as opposed to functional code calling a library), this is required. Your code can have compiling dependencies to the framework, but we all know that the framework (out of your hands) could not have compile dependencies to your code ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I use DI primarily for ease of testing.  Additionally it fosters the model of stubbing out your service calls to provide isolation and the ability to implement independent of service development.